# Facebook Messenger bot problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, chatbot

I made a messanager chatbot and tried to deploy it for the first time and after fighting with all kinds of errors I did connect my page, app and hooks.

Tough al seems working theres's no response from the bot. This is what i get in the error log.

I send "hi" and nothing back. When i google the response error that comes up, there's no solution that worked for me.

[image]

```
    'use strict'

const 
    express=require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    app=express().use(bodyParser.json()); //creates http server

    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () =>console.log('webhook is listening'));

app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
    let body=req.body;

    if(body.object === 'page'){
        body.entry.forEach(function(entry){

            //Gets the body of the webhook
            let webhook_event=entry.messaging[0];
            console.log(webhook_event);

            //Gets the sender PSID
            let sender_psid=webhook_event.sender.id;
            console.log('Sender PSID: ' + sender_psid);

        });

        res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');
    }else{
        res.sendStatus(404);
    }
    if(webhook_event.message){
        handleMessage(sender_psid, webhook_event.message);
    }else if(webhook_event.postback){
        handlePostback(sender_psid, webhook_event.postback);
    }

});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('This is EngiBot Server');
});
app.get('/webhook', (req, res) => {
    let VERIFY_TOKEN = "testbot_verify_token"

    let mode= req.query['hub.mode'];
    let token=req.query['hub.verify_token'];
    let challange = req.query['hub.challange'];

        if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === VERIFY_TOKEN) {
        res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
    } else {
        res.send('Invalid verify token');
    }

    if(mode && token){
        if(mode==='subscribe' && token === VERIFY_TOKEN){

            console.log('WEBHOOK_VERIFIED');
            res.status(200).send(challange);
        }else{
            res.sendStatus(403);
        }
    }
});

function handleMessages(sender_psid, received_message){
    let response;

    if(received_message.text){
        response = {
            "text": 'You sent the message: "${received_message.text}". Now send an image!'
        }
    }else if(received_message.attachments){
        let attachment_url=received_message.attachments[0].payload.url;
        response = {
            "attachment":{
                "type": "template",
                "payload":{
                    "template_type":"generic",
                    "elements": [{
                        "title": "Is this the right picture?",
                        "subtitle": "Tap a button to answer.",
                        "image_url": attachment_url,
                        "buttons": [
                        {
                            "type": "postback",
                            "title": "Yes!",
                            "payload":"yes",
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "postback",
                            "title": "No!",
                            "payload": "no",
                        }
                        ],
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }

    callSendAPI(sender.psid, response);
}

function handlePostback(sender_psid, received_postback){
    let response;

    let payload=received_postback.payload;

    if(payload==='yes'){
        response = {"text": "Thanks!"}
    }else if (payload==="no"){
        response ={"text": "Oops, try sending another image."}
    }
    callSendAPI(sender_psid, response);
}

function callSendAPI(sender_psid, response){
    let request_body={
        "recipient": {
        "id": sender_psid
        },
        "message": response
    }
request({
    "uri":"",
    "qs":{"access_token": PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN},
    "method": "POST",
"json": request_body
}, (err, res, body)=>{
    if(!err){
        console.log('message sent!')
    }else {
        console.error("Unable to send message:" + err);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Hey Shaggy, nice to see you after a decade! Well, for the community to understand your question in a better way-- please update your question with relevant portion of the code.

Comment: What part is needed? webhhok classes, or all classes including the bot?

Comment: I guess some code from app/index.js would help.

Comment: at least show how does your app.post('/webhook', ????) in app/index.js look like?

Comment: index.js is provided above :)

Comment: FYI this is javascript not java

Comment: i know it's not java. java is inside chatbots classes.

Comment: @ShaggyZG yes but this is a nodejs question

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem in the POST router. The 'webhook_event' is declared inside a foreach block inside a conditional block so its scope is internal to that block. To solve this you shall rewrite your code to match the scopes. This is the wrong router (i added some comments =

```
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
    let body=req.body; 
        // webhook_event == null -> true

    if(body.object === 'page'){
        body.entry.forEach(function(entry){

            //Gets the body of the webhook
            let webhook_event=entry.messaging[0]; // webhook_event declared // webhook_event == null -> false
            console.log(webhook_event);

            //Gets the sender PSID
            let sender_psid=webhook_event.sender.id;
            console.log('Sender PSID: ' + sender_psid);

        });

        res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');
        if(webhook_event.message){ // ReferenceError cause is not defined
        handleMessage(sender_psid, webhook_event.message);
    }else if(webhook_event.postback){ // ReferenceError cause is not defined
        handlePostback(sender_psid, webhook_event.postback);
    }


    }else{
        res.sendStatus(404);
    }

});
```

Comment: What do u mean rewrite comment? Move the '{' to match it inside or init the variable outside of them?

Comment: @ShaggyZG Sorry there was an error that now is fixed.

Comment: so let webhook_event; has to go below let body outside the scope of the first if statment? Can i do that without giving it any value? I know it cant be null

Comment: @Thecave3, because your let webhook_event is inside the function of call back. The scope determines where will webhook_event  be alive. Outside the function(entry){...}, webhook_event does not exist. So your if(webhook_event.message){...} does not work. If you put if(webhook_event.message){...} inside the function(entry){...}, it will work.

Comment: A side note, the usage of let and var have different implication on the live of the variable. Basically var is more like global, let is functional (local). Maybe search it on the internet, there will be better explanation than mine.

Comment: @Vivian this is true but the scope of definition and declaration is the same because of js.

Comment: @ShaggyZG well your problem in the stack trace was the one I've pointed out. So now it's up to you to change your code. I recommend you to use a lint such as 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/jslint'. I cannot write the code for you. This is the answer to your question if you update your question with your own revision I can see if you're doing it right or not.

Comment: @Thecave3 Well, tha's true. Neither i want u to write it for me. It's just nice when u get stuck and someone explains it to you and there goes the Eureka feeling lol
I changed the code a lot, found the problems fixed them, but as usual there afre new ones. Now it always asks for a new access token, which is never active, even if i put a new token. I can post my new code, will EDIT soon!